# Duda query SQL agrupar resultados distintos

Tags: sql, sql-server

me gustaría hacer una consulta SQL sobre la siguiente tabla:

| ID | OPERACION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OPERACION_1 |
| 1 | OPERACION_2 |
| 2 | OPERACION_1 |
| 3 | OPERACION_1 |
| 3 | OPERACION_1 |

En la que el resultado fuese:

| ID | OPERACION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OPERACION_1 |
| 1 | OPERACION_2 |

Resumiendo, quiero sacar los ID que contengan más de 1 operación y que además sean operaciones distintas.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego consulta comentada.

```
create table #tabla
(
    ID int,
    operacion varchar(10)
)

insert into #tabla
values(1, 'o1')
insert into #tabla
values(1, 'o2')
insert into #tabla
values(2, 'o1')
insert into #tabla
values(3, 'o1')
insert into #tabla
values(3, 'o1')


-- agrupar los registros para dejar solo ID con OPERACION diferentes
-- y guardarlos en una tabla temporal para aplicar un nuevo filtro
select id, operacion
into #TablaTemp
from #tabla
group by id, operacion

-- seleccionar de la tabla temporal los registros donde 
-- el ID exista más de una vez
select *
from #TablaTemp t
where (select COUNT(ID)
from #TablaTemp
where ID = t.ID) > 1

drop table #TablaTemp
drop table #tabla
```